# time conversion in JAVA with formula

Tags: java, time

**What I want to do?**
I want to return time and display based on user's input. Say, user enters in console `starthour: 23` `startminute: 45` `duration (in min): 30` then the period for start time will be `PM` offcourse and you can see below I calculated the start time based on the above things, but issue is calculating the endtime. For example, in the above start times, the end time should become `00:15` with the period `AM` and not `PM` like start hour.

**What I did?**

```
public String toString(){
int h = (getHour()==0 || getHour()==12) ? getHour() : getHour()%12;
String period = (getHour()<12)? "AM" : "PM";
return String.format("%02d:%02d %s", h, getMinute(), period);
}
```

**What to do?**
The above formula calculates the start time and its period, correctly, but I need a similar formula that can calculate the endhour correctly based on start hour, start minutes and duration entered by the user.

Basically, above mentioned code needs to be manipulated to figure out the endhour, endminute and its period.

Note: Please don't tell about local time use for getting end time and period. Thankyou

EDIT: Here is what I did now:

```
public String toString(){
int endh = (getEndHour()==0 || getEndHour()==12) ? getEndHour() : getEndHour()%12;
String period = ((getEndHour() + duration) <12)? "AM" : "PM";
return String.format("%02d:%02d %s", endh, getEndHour(), period);
}
```

Comment: Just as you're using getHour()%12 to convert 24 hour time to AM or PM, you can use modulo 60 if the minute after addition is greater than 60 to get the ending minutes.  If the hour after addition is greater than 24, you can use modulo 24 to get the hour in the next day (this would obviously have to be done before your 24-hour to AM/PM conversion.

Comment: @DavidChoweller, that sounds great. Would you like to give a proper answer? I can accept your answer if your code works. Thanks

Comment: @DavidChoweller, I tried what you just said, but I was not able to do so. If you don't mind can you please elaborate with the code what exactly you meant? Thanks

Comment: Update your question with the code that you tried.

Comment: @DavidChoweller, I updated the question.

Comment: You should properly format your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use 60 modulo for simplicity. here it is

```
public class Timer {
int hour;

public int getHour() {
    return hour;
}

public void setHour(int hour) {
    this.hour = hour;
}

public int getMinutes() {
    return minutes;
}

public void setMinutes(int minutes) {
    this.minutes = minutes;
}

public void addDuration(int duration) {
    hour = hour + (minutes + duration)/ 60;
    minutes = (minutes + duration) % 60;
}

int minutes;

@Override
public String toString() {
    int h = (getHour() == 0 || getHour() == 12) ? getHour()
            : getHour() % 24;
    String period = (getHour() < 12) ? "AM" : "PM";
    return String.format("%02d:%02d %s", h, getMinutes(), period);

}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Timer time = new Timer();
    time.setHour(23);
    time.setMinutes(45);
    System.out.println(time.getHour());
    time.addDuration(30);
    System.out.println(time.getHour());
    System.out.println(time);

}
```

}